# Is there a way to force autocorrect through automation object/VBE?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've written a little tool to help me manage VBA code in a few dozen Access 2003 db's, connecting via automation and using application.VBE to do comparisons and updates.

I'm running into fiddly issues with code comparison, since auto-capitalization (for recognized properties/methods/statements) only seems to run when I actually open the IDE manually.  I could just make it all case insensitive, but I'd rather get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the question is irrelevant, as the auto-cap *is* actually working.  It's just that in one database there's a textbox named "description" (lower-case), and that is overriding the caps on Err.Description, forcing it down to Err.description.